# REDHAT 8 Apache PHP SAPNWRFC gkralik / php7-sapnwrfc only works from CLI - SAP

Tags: php, apache, command-line-interface, saprfc

I'm using this repo to connect to SAP software:

https://github.com/gkralik/php7-sapnwrfc

but I don't know why my script connect and return data successfully from my `zfunctions` on SAP server only under Command Line Interface CLI

```
php /path/tomy/script.php
```

but errors under web browser always return:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SAPNWRFC\ConnectionException: Failed to set trace directory in /var/www/html/sap/test.php

or

> Exception: Could not open connection 
> Exception INFO: 
> Array 
> ( 
> [code] => 1 
> [key] => RFC_COMMUNICATION_FAILURE 
> [message] => 
> LOCATION CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host with Unicode 
> ERROR partner 123.4.5.6:3300 not reached 
> TIME Sat Feb 4 23:42:27 2023 
> RELEASE 753 
> COMPONENT NI (network interface) 
> VERSION 40 
> RC -10 
> MODULE /bas/753_REL/src/base/ni/nixxi.cpp 
> LINE 3067 
> DETAIL NiPConnect: 123.4.5.6:3300 
> SYSTEM CALL connect 
> ERRNO 13 
> ERRNO TEXT Permission denied 
> COUNTER 6 
> )

with any user, and I have checked file permissions too.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SELinux forbids Apache to make outgoing network connections. If Apache needs to make requests to an outside network service, then run the following command to allow this action.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

Comment: please mark this as an answer